# What sqlite3 query for "date range" condition that i can use?

Tags: python, sqlite, date, datetime

I'm using python and sqlite3, and i'm trying to select data from my database, based on input date range.

```
since = input("Enter date since = ")
dateuntil = input("Enter date until = ")

year, month, day = map(int, since.split('-'))
since = datetime.date(year, month, day)

year, month, day = map(int, dateuntil.split('-'))
dateuntil = datetime.date(year, month, day)

connection, cursor = connect_db()

cursor.execute("select * from dates where myDate BETWEEN ? AND ?;", since, dateuntil)
alldata = cursor.fetchall()
```

But, it shows "TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)". Any suggestion below would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.execute` takes 2 arguments: the query and the query args **tuple**.

You need to change `since, dateuntil` to a 2-element tuple: `(since, dateuntil)`:

```
cursor.execute("select * from dates where myDate BETWEEN ? AND ?;", (since, dateuntil))
```